# Why is my AJAX request sending 30 GET requests in Django Console?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to build an online store and I'm trying to give the end user the ability to filter between new, used, or all items.  I believe the way I have it set up now is that when clicking on a filter, it sends an AJAX GET  request which then loads in a different query.  The issue I'm having is that when I click on any of these filter, the page flickers and I can see in the console, 20-30 GET requests. Once in a while it will do only 1 GET request though, so I'm not sure what's happening.  I would like to figure out what's causing this issue and if it is in my jQuery or in my Django view.

TEMPLATE

```
//DISPLAYING EACH ITEM FOR SALE

{% for i in latest_entries %}
<li>
    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="item_for_sale">
            <img src="{{ i.item_picture.url }}" alt="" />
            <div class="overlayname">{{ i.headline }}</div>
            <div class="overlayprice">{{ i.price1 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="posted">Posted {{ i.pub_date|timesince|',' }} ago</div>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}


//DROP DOWN MENU TO CHOOSE FILTER

<ul class="filterlist">
    <li>
    Type
    <ul class="filterlist">
      <li><a href="" id='used'>Used</a></li>
      <li><a href="" id='new'>New</a></li>
      <li><a href="" id='strains1'>All</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


//SCRIPT TO REPOPULATE GRID WHEN FILTER IS SELECTED

<script>
function filter(type) {
  $.get("/storefront/?filter="+type, function(data) {
     $('.grid').children().remove();
     $(data).appendTo('.grid');
  });
}

$("#used").click(function () { 
  filter("used");
});

$("#new").click(function () { 
  filter("new");
  return false;
});

$("#all").click(function () { 
  filter("all");
  return false;
});
</script>
```

VIEWS

```
def storefront(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'used':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=1)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'new':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=2)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'all':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
    return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

I am having another issue (which may be related) where as soon as I click a filter, the items load onto the page but the grid appears to be 200px higher than it should be.  In other words, if I load the page, the grid of items for sale is positioned perfectly, but when I click a filter, the grid seems to move up about 200px and looks really ugly.  I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently each time I clicked a filter, it would double. So after the 5th click it would send 32 GET requests.  using 'return false' did not prevent this from happening so after reading some other SO posts, I tried:

```
$("#new").unbind()click(function () { 
  filter("new");
});
```

This worked, however my grid still loses it's positioning after loading in new items, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with masonry.js, so I am creating a new post to try to figure out that issue.